# Why user instance is not created in SQL Server 2008 (Visual Studio 2010)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and want to use SQL Server 2008 as a backend. I successfully installed SQL Server 2008 and configured it. It is even getting connected in Visual Studio 2010 unless I am trying to create a database for an particular project.

It's causing an error:

> Failed To Generate User Instance Of SQL Server Due To A Failure In Copying Database Files.The Connection Will Be Closed.

I searched and found one solution stating to delete Microsoft SQL Server data folder in user-appData... But still problem is there. What can be done to solve this issue?

[image: IMAGE SHOWS THE EXACT ERROR]

Comment: Out of interest, why have you chosen to use a completely unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: Unfortunately that's what our college told us to use.